# Как разметить данный блок?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как разметить блок, чтобы выстроить элементы в линию?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут у Вас разве линия? Как по мне то тут: первый блок - картинка, потом вертикальный блок с строкой сверху и горизонтальным блоком из двух элементов (картинка и строка) снизу.  Потом еще один блок с картинкой вконце. То есть тут как минимум 5 элементов которые не выстроены в одну линию. Или я не прав?

Comment: Если Вы выложите код того  что Вы уже сделали, то его можно будет как-то подправить, Но делать за Вас всю работу по верстке врядли кто-то захочет.

Answer (score 5):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.card {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 380px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #1976D2;
}

.info {
  margin-right: 5rem;
}

.info > div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.info > div:last-child {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #E91E63;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

button > span {
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  margin: 0.3rem 0;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

button::after,
button::before{
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  background-color: #9E9E9E;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://robohash.org/6?set=set2" alt="robot">
  <div class="info">
    <div>Business Cards</div>
    <div> 2 days delays</div>
  </div>
  <button>
    <span></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Три точки интересно реализовано.